# Fill NAs with a multiplier of the previous value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, sequence

I have a dataframe which holds an ordered list of values (var1) per country per date. Where there are NAs, I will like to fill the NAs by multiplying the value in the multiplier column by the previous value. Ultimately, this will be a growth from the previous value by the multiplier.

**Existing data frame**

```
df <- data.frame(Date = seq(ymd("2020-01-01",tz= Sys.timezone()),ymd("2020-01-05",tz= Sys.timezone()),86400),
                 Country=c(rep("USA",5),rep("INDIA",5),rep("POLAND",5),rep("SWITZERLAND",5)),
                 var1= c(20:21,rep(NA,3))
                 ,multiplier= c(rep(1.1,5),rep(1.2,5),rep(1.5,5),rep(1.1,5)))

df
         Date     Country var1 multiplier
1  2020-01-01         USA   20        1.1
2  2020-01-02         USA   21        1.1
3  2020-01-03         USA   NA        1.1
4  2020-01-04         USA   NA        1.1
5  2020-01-05         USA   NA        1.1
6  2020-01-01       INDIA   20        1.2
7  2020-01-02       INDIA   21        1.2
8  2020-01-03       INDIA   NA        1.2
9  2020-01-04       INDIA   NA        1.2
10 2020-01-05       INDIA   NA        1.2
11 2020-01-01      POLAND   20        1.5
12 2020-01-02      POLAND   21        1.5
13 2020-01-03      POLAND   NA        1.5
14 2020-01-04      POLAND   NA        1.5
15 2020-01-05      POLAND   NA        1.5
16 2020-01-01 SWITZERLAND   20        1.1
17 2020-01-02 SWITZERLAND   21        1.1
18 2020-01-03 SWITZERLAND   NA        1.1
19 2020-01-04 SWITZERLAND   NA        1.1
20 2020-01-05 SWITZERLAND   NA        1.1
```

**Expected output**
The expected output is to have the NAs in var1 filled with the product of the multiplier value and the previous value. For example var1 value for USA Jan 3rd will be 21 * 1.1 = 23.1

```
#After manipulation I should get the following
df
    Date     Country   var1 multiplier
1  1-Jan         USA 20.000        1.1
2  2-Jan         USA 21.000        1.1
3  3-Jan         USA 23.100        1.1
4  4-Jan         USA 25.410        1.1
5  5-Jan         USA 27.951        1.1
6  1-Jan       INDIA 20.000        1.2
7  2-Jan       INDIA 21.000        1.2
8  3-Jan       INDIA 25.200        1.2
9  4-Jan       INDIA 30.240        1.2
10 5-Jan       INDIA 36.288        1.2
11 1-Jan      POLAND 20.000        1.5
12 2-Jan      POLAND 21.000        1.5
13 3-Jan      POLAND 31.500        1.5
14 4-Jan      POLAND 47.250        1.5
15 5-Jan      POLAND 70.875        1.5
16 1-Jan SWITZERLAND 20.000        1.1
17 2-Jan SWITZERLAND 21.000        1.1
18 3-Jan SWITZERLAND 23.100        1.1
19 4-Jan SWITZERLAND 25.410        1.1
20 5-Jan SWITZERLAND 27.951        1.1
```

**Thanks for your response in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option in `data.table` using also `base::cumprod`:

```
library(data.table)
ix <- setDT(df)[is.na(var1), which=TRUE]
df[, var1 := as.double(nafill(var1, "locf"))][
    ix, var1 := var1 * cumprod(multiplier), Country]
```

Comment: chinsoon12.I had a feeling data.table will do the job. Thanks, it works. Can you share a resource where I can master the use of data.table?

Comment: The vignettes? Sorry not in front of computer now

Answer (score 1):

We can use `accumulate2` to after grouping by 'Country' and a group created by taking the cumulative sum of non-NA logical elements of 'var1'.  The `accumulate2` does the multiplication with 'multiplier' and replace the next element with the previous multiplied value

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    group_by(Country) %>% 
    group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(var1)), .add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(var1 = accumulate2(var1, multiplier[-1],  ~ ..1 * ..3)) %>%
    unnest(c(var1))  %>%
    as.data.frame
#          Date     Country   var1 multiplier grp
#1  2020-01-01         USA 20.000        1.1   1
#2  2020-01-02         USA 21.000        1.1   2
#3  2020-01-03         USA 23.100        1.1   2
#4  2020-01-04         USA 25.410        1.1   2
#5  2020-01-05         USA 27.951        1.1   2
#6  2020-01-01       INDIA 20.000        1.2   1
#7  2020-01-02       INDIA 21.000        1.2   2
#8  2020-01-03       INDIA 25.200        1.2   2
#9  2020-01-04       INDIA 30.240        1.2   2
#10 2020-01-05       INDIA 36.288        1.2   2
#11 2020-01-01      POLAND 20.000        1.5   1
#12 2020-01-02      POLAND 21.000        1.5   2
#13 2020-01-03      POLAND 31.500        1.5   2
#14 2020-01-04      POLAND 47.250        1.5   2
#15 2020-01-05      POLAND 70.875        1.5   2
#16 2020-01-01 SWITZERLAND 20.000        1.1   1
#17 2020-01-02 SWITZERLAND 21.000        1.1   2
#18 2020-01-03 SWITZERLAND 23.100        1.1   2
#19 2020-01-04 SWITZERLAND 25.410        1.1   2
#20 2020-01-05 SWITZERLAND 27.951        1.1   2
```

Comment: This only fills the next NA i.e value for Jan 3rd. NAs are still seen for Jan4th and 5th

Comment: Thanks akrun. I modified your answer to include a for loop and it worked.

Comment: I get an undesired output, value grows from the first value.          Date     Country      var1 multiplier grp .add
1  2020-01-01         USA  20.00000        1.1   1 TRUE
2  2020-01-02         USA  22.00000        1.1   2 TRUE
3  2020-01-03         USA  24.20000        1.1   2 TRUE
4  2020-01-04         USA  26.62000        1.1   2 TRUE
5  2020-01-05         USA  29.28200        1.1   2 TRUE
6  2020-01-01       INDIA  35.13840        1.2   1 TRUE
7  2020-01-02       INDIA  42.16608        1.2   2 TRUE

Comment: @Yinkafad i culdn't reprodduce that.  I am only ussing your input data.  are you copy/pasting the same code from my posst

Comment: @Yinkafad can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')`, and `packageVersion('purrr')`

Comment: This is the best answer -- covers extra cases too (multiplier non-constant within group, NAs not just at the end within group, etc.). +1 and should really be the top vote

Comment: @MobeusZoom thank you for checking out those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how to do this easily with `dplyr`, but it is easy enough with a loop:

```
n = nrow(df)

for(i in 2:n){
  if(is.na(df$var1[i])){
    df$var1[i] = df$var1[i - 1] * df$multiplier[i]
  }
}
```

This, of course assumes that the first row doesn't have an `NA`. If you want to handle that, you'd have to add an `if` statement.

Comment: This throws the following error.... Error in df$var1[i] <- df$var1[i - 1] * df$mutiplier[i] : 
  replacement has length zero

Comment: That's because I mispelled `multiplier`. I have fixed it. BTW your own code doesn't work because of the call to `ymd`